# How to set up a transparent(invisible) proxy with owasp zap?

Tags: zap

Burp suite can be set by checking "Support invisible proxying".
I can't find the transparent proxy settings in ZAP.

Answer (score 0):

They are in the Local Proxy Option screen.

> The local proxies can be used as intercepting/transparent proxies for both HTTP and HTTPS. For HTTPS the client applications (e.g. browser) need to use the TLS extension Server Name Indication. This allows you to set up a testing LANs (or VMs) where all HTTP and HTTPS traffic is proxied regardless of software settings.

https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/ui/dialogs/options/localproxy/

Comment: I wasn't able to proxy even though my router was forwarding 443 to 8080.
I seem the description displayed for that option is  incorrect.